# Does googlebot consider empty strings as truthy?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, googlebot, google-crawlers

I have this code on all pages of my website to track javascript errors

```
<script>
        window.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
            if (!window.XMLHttpRequest && !window.JSON) {
                return;
            }
            if (!event.filename || !event.filename.includes("mywebsite.com")) {
                // Exclude external scripts
                return;
            }
            var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
            httpRequest.open('POST', '/post-js-error', true);
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            httpRequest.send(JSON.stringify(event));
        });
    </script>
```

The 2nd if statement is meant to exclude the noise of various errors that are not related to my code (browser plugins that people have, external scripts that I installed on my website, etc)

Here's what happen: the  exclusion works pretty well so far except for one case. I receive errors from googlebots (User agent "Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html) Safari/537.36"). The filename I get is an empty string.
The error should not pass the condition if (!event.filename) but it does.

Why is that?

Comment: I don't think googlebot is executing that code. It's probably just directly hitting your URL.

Comment: Hm, I think it does because I get the event object. Especially, it has a message 'Script error.'